# request to https://rhda.rhcloud.com/api/v4/analysis failed, reason: unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image]

I believe this issue is preventing VS Code Red Hat Dependency Analytics Report to run...

response...

`Unable to analyze your stack.`

Can anyone advise how to resolve (not by turning off SSL certs)

Can't find any possible options to try with this extension

Red Hat Dependency Analytics
v0.9.3

I've filed a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/fabric8-analytics/fabric8-analytics-vscode-extension/issues/697)

Answer (score 0):

```
brew reinstall certifi
```

Reinstalling certifi seemed to fix this error.